# Converting a gray scale raw format to bmp format

Tags: image-processing, bmp, grayscale

I'm trying to write a program which rearranges pixels from a gray scale raw file according to bmp format. But I think I would make some mistakes I don't know. Could someone tells me what's wrong with the following code? specs says a pixel for BMP format consist of 3 bytes. The first row on a raw image array is placed on the bottom row on a bmp pixel array, the second row is placed on the second bottom row, and so on. so I write the core code like, except GUI code and one for bmp header:

```
void MyClass_MakeBMP(void)
{

    int i,j,k ;
    /* m_uiWidth and m_uiHeight are rows and cols for the raw image, respectively. */
    m_BMPheader.biWidth = m_uiWidth;
    m_BMPheader.biHeight = m_uiHeight;

    // raw format buffer -> 2d array.
    // bmp format buffer -> 1d array.
    // m_pcImgbuf is 1d array for a raw file.
    // m_pcBMP is 2d array to be copied from m_pcImgbuf.

    for(i = 0 ; i < m_uiHeight; i++)
    {
        k = -1; // index into m_pcImgbuf.
        for(j = 0 ; j < m_uiWidth * 3; j++)
        {
            if( j % 3 == 0)
                k++;

            m_pcBMP[i * m_uiHeight + j] = m_pcImgbuf[(m_uiHeight - 1) - i][k];

        }
    }



}
```

Also, I don't care about padding, because this program can takes as input, 256*256, 128*128, and 512*512 images. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation for the destination offset is wrong.

```
m_pcBMP[i * 3*m_uiWidth + j] = ...
```